# How can i open iPhone phone App with Recent Call summary from my iOS App?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hi I want to show the recent call summary by opening the phone app from my iOS App.Please any body suggest how it is possible?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is not possible in iOS. This is to provide security and privacy iOS User.

Comment: Not much to do with security (it's not like your app can get the data back once it just launches another app via url), but yeah, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SpyPhone project on GitHub.

For example, you can get the most recently dialed number like so:

```
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mobilephone.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *lastDialed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [d valueForKey:@"DialerSavedNumber"]];
```

This works for iOS6. I would not expect Apple to be happy with this sort of functionality anymore. Any way try it in iOS 7 and 8